# jwplayer can't play video in iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, video, jwplayer

i want to integrate jwplayer in my webapplication to play .mov videos in iPhone, iPad.

After integrated jwplayer, jwplayer is not play the video from video folder which is contains all training videos [ e:\video – in my local machine].

But if I put .mov file into my project resource folder then, jwplayer can play the video. It can also play the video's from url.

The following jwplayer sample is NOT working

```
var    selectedTrainingPlayer = jwplayer("videoContainerDiv").setup({
                 'flashplayer': '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/mediaplayer-5.10/player.swf',
                 'id': 'playerId',
                 'width': '642',
                 'height': '412',
                 'mute': false,
                 'volume' : '100',
                 'controlbar' : 'bottom',
                 'repeat': 'list',
                 'volume': 100,
                 'stretching' : 'exactfit',
                 'image': '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/spring/getVideoThumbnail?videoId='+trainingVideoId,
                 'file': '<%=request.getContextPath() %>/spring/video/1.mov'

            });
```

But jwplayer can play the video’s from URL’s or golflessons resource folder, please refer the following code

```
var    selectedTrainingPlayer = jwplayer("videoContainerDiv").setup({
                 'flashplayer': '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/mediaplayer-5.10/player.swf',
                 'id': 'playerId',
                 'width': '642',
                 'height': '412',
                 'mute': false,
                 'volume' : '100',
                 'controlbar' : 'bottom',
                 'repeat': 'list',
                 'volume': 100,
                 'stretching' : 'exactfit',
                 'image': '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/spring/getVideoThumbnail?videoId='+trainingVideoId,
                 'file': '<%=request.getContextPath() %> /resources/images/golflessons/Pro_Book myself_Single_Lesson.mov',

            });
```

While jwplayer is not playing the video, eclipse shows the following error like

Caused by: java.io.IOException: **An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine**     at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)     at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)     at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)     at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)     at org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:170)     at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:221)     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:725).

**My Understanding :**

jwplayer can access the videos from url and  golflessons resource folder. But it unable to access the video's from outside of the project folder.

i have tried with disable firewall and antivirus, but no solution is working for me.

But the same workflow is working in my windows desktop, problem only in iPhone and iPad

please anyone guide me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are using JW5 here.

Under this line:

```
'volume': 100,
```

Add:

```
'provider': 'video',
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: No i have that solution also... but still it's not working, and throws same errors ... Can i try jwplayer 6?

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support.. i can't understand your message " Do you have a link?". Did you mean login account in jwplayer?

Comment: I mean a link to where you are trying to embed the player on your website.

Comment: What type of a file is this? loadVideoFile.htm

Comment: Thanks for your continues support. i use .mov files

Comment: I would check how the file was encoded. Try to test with this one - http://www.bogotobogo.com/VideoStreaming/Files/nginxSmoothStream/BigBuckBunny/bunny.mov

Comment: Dear Ethan, Thanks for your support. Now i find out actual problem. Actual problem is my java code is not stream data as expected manner. Now i use third party media servers and now my problem was solved. thanks a lot for your help